# lxml etree.XLST transform returns empty on linux

Tags: python, linux, xslt, lxml

With code like this:

```py
xml_file = open(xml_filepath, 'r'. 'utf-8')
xml_content = xml_file.read()
xml_file.close()

xml_tree = etree.fromstring(xml_content.encode('utf-8'))

xsl_file = open(xsl_filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
xsl_content = xsl_file.read()
xsl_file.close()

xsl_tree = etree.XML(xsl_content, parser=etree.XMLParser(), base_url=os.path.dirname(xsl_filepath) + os.sep)

transform = etree.XSLT(xsl_tree)

tran_result = transform(xml_tree)

print(tran_result)
```

Its **works fine on windows**, but transform() returns empty 'XSLTResultTree' on linux.

Here's some package version info:

```
python: 3.10.6
lxml: 4.9.2

linux:
libxml2: 2.9.14
libxslt: 1.1.37
```

thanks.

Comment: It is easier to help with a proper [mcve]. We cannot run the code in the question since `xml_filepath` and `xsl_filepath` are undefined. Also, your code seems more complicated than it needs to be. If you have XML and XSLT as files, just use `etree.parse()` on them.

Comment: @myzh215219 – 
`'r'. 'utf-8'`?

Comment: What modules did you import?  Show complete working code.